# Partial update into large document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing the problem about performance. My application is about chatting.

I designed mapping index with nested object like below.

```
{
  "conversation_id-v1": {
    "mappings": {
      "stream": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "analyzerName": {
                "type": "text",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "analyzer": "analyzerName"
              },
              "language": {
                "type": "langdetect",
                "analyzer": "_keyword",
                languages: ["en", "ko", "ja"]
              }
            }
          },
          "comments": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "message": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "analyzerName": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                  "analyzer": "analyzerName"
                },
                "language": {
                  "type": "langdetect",
                  "analyzer": "_keyword",
                  languages: ["en", "ko", "ja"]
                }
              }
            }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

** actually have a lot of fields

A document has around 4,000 nested objects. When I upsert data into document, It peak the cpu to 100% also disk i/o in case write. Input ratio around 1000/s.

How can I tuning to improve performance?

Hardware

3x 2vCPUs 13GB on GCP

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, do get a recommendation about performance tuning you need to explain why you need custom analyzers and 4000 nested objects.

Comment: Because I'd like to search comments in nested and come with their parent stream for display. For analyzer, I have to tokenize message in some language for query string.

Comment: Seems like a design issue, operations on nested objects are always costly. I am assuming that you are storing post and their comments in the index and then searching in comments to return matching post. For this case, better just create comment index with post_id, then aggregate distinct post ids to return. And then post data can be returned from DB.

Comment: There is also "join" data type https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html, aka parent/child.

Comment: @khachik it's good performance?

Comment: @Bongsakorn As good as it can be, but again, this seems to be a design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**4000 nested fields sounds like a lot** - if I were you, I would look long and hard at your mapping design to be very certain you actually need that many nested fields.

Quoting from the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects):

```
Internally, nested objects index each object in the array as a separate hidden document.
```

Since a document has to be fully reindexed on update, you're indexing 4000 documents with a single update.

**Why so many fields?**

The reason you gave in the comments for needing so many fields

```
I'd like to search comments in nested and come with their parent stream for display.
```

makes me think that you may be mixing two concerns here.

ElasticSearch is meant for search, and your mapping should be optimized for search. If your mapping shape is dictated by the way you want to display information, then something is wrong.

**Design your index around search**

Note that by "search" I mean both indexing and querying.

For the use case you have, it seems like you could:

- Index only the comments, with a reference (some id) to the parent stream in the indexed `comment` document.
- After you get the search results (a list of comments) back from the search index, you can retrieve each comment along with its parent stream from some other data source (e.g. a relational database).

The point is, it may be much more efficient to re-retrieve the comment along with whatever else you want from some other source that is more better than ElasticSearch at joining data.

Comment: good point, but by my design I would like to combine searched comments in one document and can paginate. So this way made me got the affect.